# Getting Chinese Text in TimePicker Component

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

I have written the code for a TimePicker but the text is chinese.

```
<nz-form-item>
<nz-form-label nzFor="shiftTimings">Shift Timings</nz-form-label>
<nz-form-control>
  <nz-time-picker formControlName="shiftTimings"></nz-time-picker>
  <button *ngIf="multiShifts" nz-button nzType="default" nzShape="circle" [nzSize]="small"><i class="anticon anticon-plus"></i></button>
</nz-form-control>
```

Can anybody help?
[Image with input box with Chinese writing saying "Select Time"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccvnl.png)

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

The standard method described in the docs.

In `app.module` add

```
import { NgZorroAntdModule, NZ_I18N, en_US } from 'ng-zorro-antd';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import en from '@angular/common/locales/en';
registerLocaleData(en);
```

and in the providers array, add:

```
  providers: [{ provide: NZ_I18N, useValue: en_US }],
```

PS: This **does not work** **if NgZorroAntdModule is loaded in a feature module** (last verified on ngZorro 7.5.0) In such a case, go for Method 2.

**Method 2:**

In the `component` you are using the date picker, call ngZorro's i18n service and change the language:

```
  import { en_US, NzI18nService } from 'ng-zorro-antd';
    ..
    constructor(private i18n: NzI18nService) {
    }
    ....
    ngOnInit() {
         this.i18n.setLocale(en_US);
    }
```

PS: You can also set this from any component that is loaded first.

Comment: Actually works, thank you sir! And needed to use Method 2 because it's in a wrapped feature module.

Comment: I used this for the Pagination issue, not the datepicker, but it's the same issue